# How to remove blank page when using newpage

Tags: page-breaking

By the way, after creating cover on bookclass, I tried to use `\newpage`. When I was trying to type random sentence, it works fine.

But, when I added this earlier:

```
\begin{center}
       \chapter*{\textbf{TITLE}}
\end{center}
```

It created a blank page between the cover and the chapter I'm working on.

How to fix this?

My code is:

```
\newpage
\begin{center}
       \chapter*{\textbf{TITLE}}
\end{center}
 %text here
```

---

### EDIT

I'll show my full codes. I'm splitting my TeX files into 3 part and using `\include{...}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{cover1}
\include{cover2}

\mainmatter %

\end{document}
```

My codes for `cover2.tex`

```
\newpage
\begin{center}
\chapter*{\textbf{RINGKASAN}}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{RINGKASAN}}
%TEXT HERE
```

Comment: Erh, (1) that is not how one centers a chapter title, (2) why is the center env enced vy `\end{chapter}`? (3) This will clearly create a compilation error, never ignore compilation errors.

Comment: oh lol. That's a typo actually sorry. i'll edit asap. But my main document use \end{center}

Comment: @daleif btw should i show all of my codes including \documentclass{...} ?

Comment: You're doing it right now, but you are including stuff others don't have. Again I ask you why you are trying to make a title tile that? `\chapter*` is not meant to design a title page. Why not just use `\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries RINGKASAN\end{center}`. If it is a cover why is it in the TOC?

Comment: @daleif the name was cover doesn't mean it's a cover. That page contains acknowledgement and foreword. Something like that.

Comment: Then why should this be centered if the rest of the chapter headers are not? That gives the document an inconsistent look\

Comment: @daleif i'll center the rest later. And btw i put toc after acknowledgement and foreword. I'm so so sorry if this confuses you.

Comment: As an information. I'm not really show all of my codes. There's still cover2.tex but it's too long to include here. And i just put some importants code here. Again i'm really sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: `\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{foo} bah \chapter*{baz}
\end{document}` also produces a blank  page. Is not a mistake to fix, it what `\chapter` does (among other things) by default: start in a new odd page, no matter it is. So,  your best options here are  (a) be happy for so clever command  (b)  use the  `openany` or `oneside` options in `\documentclass`, or (c) not  use `\chapter` but a big and bold normal text, as daleif suggested.

Comment: BTW, `\begin{center}\chapter*{baz}\end{center}`  will not center "baz". But `\chapter*{\centering baz}`  will work as expected. However, this is not the optimal approach but redefine the chapter command, to center the title only typing `\chapter*{baz}`.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion! I got what i want.